# Java hangs with openConnection in new thread

Tags: java, http

I'm building an app which invoke in separate thread an API request to REST API. This app still hangs after invoking the call - no exception thrown.

I was trying a lot of methods to make an GET request from my Java app but none on them worked out.

```java
class ThreadRunner {

    public ThreadRunner() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        ThreadRunner threadRunner = new ThreadRunner();
        threadRunner.startChecking();

    }





    public void startChecking() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                APIUtils.sendGet("https://app01.mysimpledomain.abc/api/v2/user/1");
            }

        });

        thread.setName("ThreadRunner");
        //thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();



    }

}
```

```java
class APIUtils {

    public static void sendGet(String url) {


        try {
            System.out.println("Before invoking my url...");
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // optional default is GET
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // add request header
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println( "response: " + response.toString() );
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            System.out.println( "HttpStatusCodeException e: " + e.getMessage() );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println( "Exception e: " + e.getMessage() );
//          LOG.error(e, e);
        }

    }
}
```

The messages stops after print "Before connection...". I should see the output from my API.

I want to say that api calls works from chrome / firefox / postman.

Edit:

With URL for method APIUtils.sendGet: http://www.google.com/search?q=mkyong works but with my API url hangs before

Edit2:

URL from my API works and gives a JSON in Chrome / Firefox / Postman.

Comment: is this working without using new thread? try to use try catch block .

Comment: The method startCheck() does absolutely nothing.

Comment: I've added additional code - please check now

Comment: Why did you set the thread daemon? That means the application will quit without letting it finish. Probably doesn't even get a chance to start in this case.

Comment: @matt what do you mean "thread daemon" ? Could you say something more ?

Comment: Exactly, if you don't know what `thread.setDaemon(true);` does, why have you used it?

Comment: @matt I found this in some code snippet so I've used it. Should I comment this?

Comment: If you setDaemon, then your application can quit before the threads run method has finished. Do you want the application to quit before the thread has finished? Right now there is no reason for a thread. Defnitely remove the setDaemon.

Comment: @matt commented this and edited - please check now

Comment: Now it should at least run through some of it. It looks like your url is malformed, so you should  be seeing a exception. Notice all of the differences between your url and the one supplied. (eg. http:// vs no protocol, specifying a port in the url.)

Comment: @matt edited for the 2nd time - check now

Comment: Have you considered [connecting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()) after using openConnection? `It should be noted that a URLConnection instance does not establish the actual network connection on creation. This will happen only when calling URLConnection.connect().`

Comment: Also, you should be getting an exception if it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It may throwing exception. write the code to catch particular exception and try to resolve it.
here is the working code

```
 String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=mkyong";
    try {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(response.toString());
   } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            attempts++;
  } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(e, e);
 }
```

Comment: This worked out, but when I changed the url variable to my API get request - it stopped before try block. Do you have any idea why?